# Field injection of singleton class

Tags: java, singleton, guice

I have interface:

```
public interface DataStorage {
    boolean setData(String dataName);

    boolean unsetData(String dataName);

    Map getData();
}
```

And his implementation:

```
public class DataStorageImpl implements DataStorage {

    private Map dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized boolean setData(String dataName) {
        dataMap.put(dataName, true);

        return true;
    }

    public synchronized boolean unsetData(String dataName) {
        dataMap.put(dataName, false);

        return true;
    }

    public synchronized Map getData() {
        return dataMap;
    }
}
```

Guice module implementation:

```
public class DataStorageModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(DataStorage.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("DataStorage")).to(DataStorageImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to inject DataStorage to my Netty request handler. Request handler code:

```
public class DataMethodsHandler {
    @Inject @Named("DataStorage")
    private DataStorage dataStorage;

    public String version() {
        return "0.0.1";
    }

    public Map list_data() {
        return dataStorage.getData();
    }

    public boolean set_data(String dataName) {
        return dataStorage.setData(dataName);
    }

    public boolean unset_data(String dataName) {
        return dataStorage.unsetData(dataName);
    }
}
```

And code responsible for binding request handler to Netty:

```
    PropertyHandlerMapping phm = new CustomPropertyHandlerMapping();
    phm.setVoidMethodEnabled(true);
    try {
        phm.addHandler("", dataMethodsHandler.class);
    } catch (XmlRpcException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I'm calling XMLRPC method "set_data" request fails, because dataStorage field in DataMethodsHandler is null. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your `PropertyHandlerMapping` is not using Guice to instantiate the `DataMethodsHandler`

Comment: @TavianBarnes thank you. I just started learning Guice. If you do not complicate can you provide a link or tell me key words for searching in Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. First of all we should replace default RequestProcessorFactoryFactory method getRequestProcessorFactory which call Class.newInstance() with this code:

```
public class XmlRpcServerClientRequestProcessorFactoryFactory implements RequestProcessorFactoryFactory {

    @Inject
    private Injector injector;
    @Inject
    public XmlRpcServerClientRequestProcessorFactoryFactory(Injector injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
    }

    @Override
    public RequestProcessorFactory getRequestProcessorFactory(final Class pClass)
            throws XmlRpcException {
        return new RequestProcessorFactory() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public Object getRequestProcessor(XmlRpcRequest pRequest)
                    throws XmlRpcException {
                return injector.getInstance(pClass);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Create module for Guice:

```
public class NettyXmlRpcModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(NettyXmlRpcModule.class);
        bind(XmlRpcServerClientRequestProcessorFactoryFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Integer.TYPE).annotatedWith(Names.named("xmlrpc.port")).toInstance(3133);
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Log providesLog(){
        return LogFactory.getLog(NettyXmlRpcWebServer.class);
    }

    @Provides
    InetAddress providesInetAddress() throws UnknownHostException {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    }
}
```

And than set new factory for handler:

```
PropertyHandlerMapping phm = new CustomPropertyHandlerMapping();
        phm.setRequestProcessorFactoryFactory(xmlRpcServerClientRequestProcessorFactoryFactory);

phm.setVoidMethodEnabled(true);
try {
    phm.addHandler("", methodsHandler);
} catch (XmlRpcException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
xmlRpcServer.setHandlerMapping(phm);
```

Now handler will catch all requests, all fields with annotations will be injected.

Comment: Some advise: You should either use field-injection or constructor injection, not both. And whenever you need to inject the injector, take a step back and re-think your design. Normally, having a single injector create your whole instance tree is enough (e.g. in a main() method or a servlet filter). And last: what is a FactoryFactory? Using guice/DI will make most factories obsolete, since you configure the creation of instances in your modules, use providers or generic factories with assisted injection ...

Comment: @JanGalinski thank you for your advise. FactoryFactory is a strange interface from Apache's XMLRpc library. I cant change behaviour of this library completely, but with overrided methods works good.